# What search terms can help me find "progressive reveal" campaigns?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, terminology

not sure what this is called. Tried a bit of googling but didn't find what I was looking for.
I'm designing a website on which we will be revealing a list item every week. The website is launching with "Item 1" already up, but I want to make it clear that there are other items coming/planned.

I want to look for some inspiration or design tips but I have no idea what to call that sort of layout and how to find info on it. 
Is there a specific name for this sort of layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow; I did a bit of a search and I cannot find a term for it either. I am assuming what you are thinking of is what they do in games when new levels are not yet released such as AngryBirds:

[image]

One game simply uses a cloud with something shiny peeking out from underneath.

[image]
[image]

Another way would possibly be a dotted line around a grayed out product.

I could not answer your question about a term, but perhaps this could inspire.

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest :: it's down to creativity. There will never be an exact template or means to display your content.

Here are some ideas for inspiration:

http://www.instantshift.com/2012/02/29/50-fresh-examples-of-creative-coming-soon-page-design/

http://www.instantshift.com/2013/07/30/coming-soon-page-essentials/

Just look through them and pick up on snippets to create your own idea, I was able to just from looking briefly over them

Comment: Hi Wckd, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? I also think that this may be a little different than what was originally asked. These examples are for coming soon web sites. I think the original question is asking more of, how can I promote a product and also promote that there will be future products coming.

Comment: Fair enough: but as mentioned, "promotion" of content, is open to interpretation as well as open to creative inspiration. Therefore there isn't an exact site or template to go to that will tell you "how to do it".

Comment: Hi Wckd, thanks for the links!
Like AndrewH kind of said, I was more looking into how that type of layout would be called. 
Ex: "Empty state design" is known to be a design for when you have no items in a layout. (Ex "You have no songs in your playlist. Add some songs!" or "You have no items in the trash. Goodie!")

I was wondering if there was a term that could help me find some examples of "progressive revealing".